# Touchless Control 3.15.0.1 Cannot uninstall

Tags: uninstallation

My Motorola Ultra with Android version 4.2.2 contains 3.15.0.1 Touchless Control. I have uninstalled the software both from Google Play and App Settings. However, the device still says "Update", instead of "install".

How can I successfully uninstall the Touchless Control?

Note: The reason why I would like to uninstall it would pertain to the reason for installing the most updated version.

Comment: Does it say "Uninstall" or "Disable"? If the latter, then it is a system app which cannot be removed (by normal means). You need to disable it if you want it gone. However, you don't need to remove it to install a newer version. Just run the update.

Comment: It says "Uninstall". I uninstalled it and ran the update. However, Touchless Control still possess 3.15.01 version.

Comment: Then I am unclear exactly what it is you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: I changed my current build, and it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: @FranzNoel Can you post your last comment (and specify what build, etc) as an answer, and mark it as an answer later? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem unable to remove Touchless Chat. Please follow this method and you are able to remove this software from your phone.

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/how-remove-virus-from-android-phone-or-tablet-image-gunpoder-3605390/

After step 1, go to step 3 and in security Device administrator you will see Touchless software, uncheck it and then uninstall option give you to uninstall.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).